# Ionic ion-toggle and radio-group click event?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am using Ionic3, and would like to have an html element ([`ion-toggle`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toggle/Toggle/) and [`radio-group`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/radio/RadioGroup/)), that if I click on, it fires a javascript function.

As you can see below, I gave added a `ng-click` attibute based on [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-list-item-with-ng-click-and-option-buttons/5078/3), but it does not invoke the javascript function.

Any advise appreciated.

**settings.html**

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-click="notifications()">
    <ion-label>Notifications</ion-label>
    <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="personModel.notifications" id="notifications">Notifications</ion-toggle>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>

<br>

<ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="personModel.milesKm" id="milesKm">
  <ion-item ng-click="milesKm()">
    <ion-label>Km</ion-label>
    <ion-radio value="0"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item ng-click="milesKm()">
    <ion-label>Miles</ion-label>
    <ion-radio value="1"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

**settings.ts**

```
  notifications(): void {
    alert('notifications');
  }

  milesKm(): void {
    alert('milesKm');
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-click` is an AngularJS (angular 1) syntax and will not work in Angular >= 2.

[`ion-radio`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/radio/RadioButton/) has `ionSelect` output event and [`radio-group`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/radio/RadioGroup/) has `ionChange` event.

So you can either:

```
<ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="personModel.milesKm" id="milesKm">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Km</ion-label>
    <ion-radio value="0" (ionSelect)="milesKm()"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item ng-click="milesKm()">
    <ion-label>Miles</ion-label>
    <ion-radio value="1" (ionSelect)="milesKm()"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Or :

```
 <ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="personModel.milesKm" id="milesKm" (ionChange)="milesKm()">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Km</ion-label>
    <ion-radio value="0"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item ng-click="milesKm()">
    <ion-label>Miles</ion-label>
    <ion-radio value="1"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Or [`ion-item`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/item/Item/) has simple `click` event.

```
<ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="personModel.milesKm" id="milesKm">
  <ion-item (click)="milesKm()">
    <ion-label>Km</ion-label>
    <ion-radio value="0"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item (click)="milesKm()">
    <ion-label>Miles</ion-label>
    <ion-radio value="1"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```